# How would one store crypto data on client side persistently

Tags: javascript, encoding, cryptography, arraybuffer

I am using libsignal for some personal project. The library says i need to store the generated identity key pair for each client on the client side. But considering development in a web browser, the only place this could happen is localstorage.

But considering that the Identity key pair generated is in the form of

```
// keyPair -> { pubKey: ArrayBuffer, privKey: ArrayBuffer }
// Store identityKeyPair somewhere durable and safe.
```

Localstorage only stores strings, and objects need to be 'stringify'ed.

Could anyone give insight as to how to would be done or how clients like whatsapp do it.

Comment: IMO whatsapp relies on normal SSL for communication between the mobile client and the browser. The pairs would be stored on the mobile client itself

Comment: I see, i thought of that, but thought they would some sort of better mechanism to maintain that. But to my original problem of storing data on client side and maintaining object as is, any ideas?

Comment: How about web storage? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage

Comment: [See this blog tutorial](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/) on using the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). It allows you to store binary blobs, which would include `ArrayBuffer`'s.